# Pass an argument from one form to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main form and a subform. The subform is activated by 4 different form events in the main form and is redesigned depending on which event triggered it. But rather than using a global boolean to determine which event was triggered, is there a way to pass an argument directly to the subform?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "pass" an argument?

Comment: Sorry, I always thought parse was the correct spelling

Comment: They mean two different things. You want pass as in "pass the parcel/variable", right?

Comment: Parsing is the process of analysing a string of symbols.

Comment: I am brilliantly displaying my lack of fundamental knowledge here. Ok, I've changed the spelling! I did mean pass, I don't want to analyse anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a public member to the subform. Either a method or a property. For instance

```
public void ProcessEvent(int eventNumber)
{
    switch (eventNumber) {
        case 1:
            // Process event #1
            break;
        case 2:
            // Process event #2
            break;
        case 3:
            // Process event #3
            break;
        case 4:
            // Process event #4
            break;
    }
}
```

In the main form you would call it like this:

```
mySubform.ProcessEvent(1);
```

*(Note: In WinForms you would not use a subform but a `UserControl`.)*

---

Or with a property in the subform:

```
public int EventNumber { get; set; }
```

In the main form you would set it like this:

```
mySubform.EventNumber = 1;
```

In the subform you can simply access it like this

```
if (EventNumber == 1) { ... }
```

---

Note: Forms, subforms and Controls are just classes and you can do with them all you can do with "normal" classes.

---

**UPDATE**

According to one of your comments, you are not using a subform but a dialog form. *I would call a form (UserControl or MDI form) placed on (not above) another form as subform.* You would call it like this:

```
var fldg = new MyDialogForm{ EventNumber = 1 };  // Using the property described above.
fdlg.ShowDialog(this);
```

Yet another option is to pass an argument to the constructor of the subform

```
private int _eventNumber;

public MyDialogForm(int eventNumber) // Constructor
{
    _eventNumber = eventNumber;
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
var fldg = new MyDialogForm(1);  // Pass the argument to the constructor.
fdlg.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: I probably should have said but it is when I use ShowDialog() in the main form, so it goes into the Load event of the subform. That is where I need to pass an argument to if possible.

Comment: This works just fine, thank you. I was hoping there was a more encapsulated way but it is quite trivial I guess

Comment: Well, then you are not really dealing with a subform. That would be a form added to a form like a control. I updated my question.

Comment: Excellent. Your update is just what I'm looking for. Thank you